# ASP.Net Grid Export to Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, export-to-excel

I am using following code to export my `GridView` to `Excel`:

```
string attachment = "attachment; filename=Contacts.xls";
Response.ClearContent();
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
gvReports.RenderControl(htw);
Response.Write(sw.ToString());
Response.End();
```

This code is copied from [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/DipalChoksi/exportxl_asp2_dc11032006003657AM/exportxl_asp2_dc.aspx) site. I have followed all the instructions but after executing nothing happened. No exception (Except `Thread.Abort` which is, I think, because of `Response.End()`).

I have also used `Response.Flush()` BUT nothing is happening no exception or file etc.

Thanks.

**EDIT Now Code Is like following:**

My GridView is in Control. The control is on asp.net page and that page has following method.

```
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
{

}
```

Click event of button in ascx control:

```
protected void btnExportToExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ExportToExcel();
}

private void ExportToExcel()
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
      "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.xls");
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel ";
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    gvReports.AllowPaging = false;
    gvReports.DataBind();
    gvReports.RenderControl(hw);
    Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
}
```

gvReports has no link, checkbox etc. 5 bound columns and 1 button.

Nothing is happening.

Comment: gvReports.DataBind(); should be called

Comment: Please see edit after answer of @MMK

Answer (score 0):

**UserControl code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO;

public partial class WebUserControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            this.gridView.DataSource = this.SqlDataSource1;
            this.gridView.DataBind();

    }
    private void excel_Export()
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
          "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.xls");
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel ";
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        this.gridView.AllowPaging=false;
        this.gridView.DataBind();
        this.gridView.RenderControl(hw);
        Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        excel_Export();
    }
}
```

**User Control Hosting page:**

```
 <asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
        <uc1:WebUserControl ID="WebUserControl1" runat="server" />
    </asp:Content>
```

You really dont need following event in code behind of User control hosting page, because excel export is being done via user control which contains grid view and button.

```
 public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
 {
        /* Verifies that the control is rendered */
 }
```

Hopefully this will you help to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

itextsharp dlls ,you will get the best method to do that

[Click here](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/04/how-to-export-gridview-data-to-pdf.html)

Comment: isn't iTextSharpt for PDFs only?

Comment: no you can convert gridview to excel ,word ,csw and pdf too ,without affected by paging ,see the link I have provided.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using MVC3 for my solution, but the code I'm using to push data out to an excel file is:

```
        var grid = new GridView
        {
            DataSource = from lineItem in rows
                         select new
                         {
                             lineItem.ProjectName,
                             lineItem.Sat,
                             lineItem.Sun,
                             lineItem.Mon,
                             lineItem.Tue,
                             lineItem.Wed,
                             lineItem.Thu,
                             lineItem.Fri
                         }
        };
        var fileName = string.Format("{0}:{1}", userName, timesheetDate);
        grid.DataBind();

        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName + ".xls");
        Response.ContentType = "application/msexcel";
        var sw = new StringWriter();
        var htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        grid.RenderControl(htw);
        Response.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.End();
```

The immediate differences that I see are:

```
I take my data and create a new GridView
Response.ClearContent() instead of a Response.Clear()
Response.Write instead of Response.Output.Write
```

Everything else looks the same, and we both are using a click event to call a void function. So I'm guessing that if you make those few changes, your code should start working for you.

It's been a while since I implemented this solution and I couldn't find the sites that I got this off of so I can't show you my original sources. Sorry about that.